# How to measure the length of pyramid's edge in electron microscope photo using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

There is a electron microscope photo of some surface:

[image]

What I want to do is to use OpenCV to detect edges of pyramid in this image and measure their length. Currently I have to label them manually (the red lines in image).

[image]

I try to use Canny with Hough transform but the result turn out not very well.

```py
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('../data/sample.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

kernel_size = 9
blur_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (kernel_size, kernel_size), 0)

lo, hi = 15, 27
edges = cv2.Canny(blur_gray, lo, hi)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(blur_gray)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(edges)

lines
 = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 50, None, 50, 10)
```

[image]

It looks to me like there is too much noise in the original image. What I want to detect is the lateral edges of pyramid, but the base edges are also included with my code. I don't know how to remove them before using Canny and Hough transform. And there are some glitches in the result of edge detection which I don't know how to eliminate them. I though Gaussian blur should be enough but it turns out not working very well.

I have to confess that I have little knowledge of computer vision so I am not sure what's the right tool for this. It would be really appreciated to have someone shed some light on it. There is no need to find a 100% accuracy method as there are some abnormal structures in the image that have to be adjust manually, what I want is try to reduce the human effort as much as possible by using some computer vision technique.